# Discord.js logical operator isn't working with my arguments

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot returns a message when the first arg isn't one of the options i have put but it isn't working and keeps sending the messages even if the arg was red or blue

```js
if(args[0] !== 'red' || 'blue') return message.channel.send('That isn\'t a valid color')
```

Comment: `"red" || "blue"` evaluates to `"red"`. So, you're basically checking if `args[0]` is not `red`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code: `args[0] !== 'red' || 'blue'`, the `!==` operator has higher precedence than `||`, so it behaves like `(args[0] !== 'red') || 'blue'`.

This is completely valid in JS, because the `||` operator will return the non-boolean operand if found.

So
`true || 'blue' == true`

and
`false || 'blue' == 'blue' == true`

One solution:

`if(args[0] !== 'red' && args[0] !== 'blue')`

Comment: would i be able to use "&&" many times? i want to put other choices

Comment: You should use something like `['red','blue','yellow'].includes(args[0])` if you have more items to check.